# Shuffling an array or arrays in Objective-C

Tags: arrays, nsmutablearray, 2d

I have an array of integers, I want split this array into smaller arrays of integers, then put these smaller arrays into a new array, shuffle this new array, and repopulate the original array with the shuffled integers. The result will be a shuffled version of the original array, but each individual item will not be shuffled, instead chunks of the original will be shuffled.

I can do this in Java, C# so on, but new to Objective-C, so any examples would be helpful.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
NSMutableArray *chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int x = 0; x < [rawData count]; x += 400){
    NSMutableArray *chunk = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int y = 0; y < 400; y++){ //chunks of 400 items
        [chunk addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rawData[x + y]]];
    }
    count ++;
}
//shuffle chunks
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [chunks count]; i ++ ){
    for (int y = 0; y < 400; y++) {
        //how do I put the chunks chunk back into the rawData[index]??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for (note that you count iterate to 400 in your second loop... you have to stop at 'chunk.count'):

```
for(int i = 0; i < [chunks count]; i ++ ){
  NSMutableArray *chunk = [chunks objectAtIndex:i];
  for (int y = 0; y < [chunk count]; y++) {
    [rawData replaceObjectAtIndex:i*400+y withObject:[chunk objectAtIndex:y]];
```